# React native props: google maps

Tags: react-native, props

estoy usando la libreria react-native-maps en mi proyecto de react-native, hice un componente que renderiza el mapa, y ese componente lo quiero importar a otro componente que debe pasar los datos de ubicación como props, pero por alguna razón el mapa no los toma, alguien sabe como los puedo pasar?

(Este es mi componente que renderiza el mapa, HospitalMapRender)

```
interface Props {
    markOrigin: {
        latitude: number
        longitude: number
    }
}

export const HospitalMapRender: React.FC<Props> = (props) => {
    const { markOrigin } = props
    const [destination, setDestination] = React.useState({
        latitude: 19.394095,
        longitude: -99.281383
    })

    return (
        <View>
            <MapView
                style={Styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: markOrigin.latitude,
                    longitude: markOrigin.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.006,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.006
                }}
            >
                <Marker coordinate={markOrigin} />
                <Marker coordinate={destination} />
                <MapViewDirections
                    origin={markOrigin}
                    destination={destination}
                    strokeColor="red"
                    strokeWidth={2}
                    apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_KEY}
                />
            </MapView>
        </View>
    )
}
```

(Este es mi componente que recibe el componente del mapa, y debe pasar los props)

```
    <View style={Styles.mapContainer}>
        <View style={Styles.map}>
            <HospitalMapRender
                markOrigin={{
                    longitude: 19.410274,
                    latitude: -99.272246
                }}
            />
        </View>
    </View>
```